# Proper way of selecting created element?

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error message of `TypeError: Node.removeChild: Argument 1 is not an object` when trying to `select my 'resetBtn'` in my `removeReset() function`. You will have to `click` the game until you or the player `wins five times`. The reset button shows up, it gets clicked and even though it goes away I still get this error.

What is the proper way to target this element?

The error message is coming from this

`document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('#buttonReset'));`

In the `removeReset()`. Below is the `javascript and html code`. Thank you

```js
const resetBtn = document.createElement("button");
resetBtn.id = 'buttonReset';

const rock = document.getElementById('submitRock');
const paper = document.getElementById('submitPaper');
const scissors = document.getElementById('submitScissors');

rock.addEventListener("click", function() {
  choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  playRound(choices[0]);
});

paper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  playRound(choices[1]);
});

scissors.addEventListener('click', function() {
  choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  playRound(choices[2]);
});

function updateScore() {
  if (document.getElementById("ps").innerText === '5') {
    document.getElementById("finalScore").innerText = `Player Wins!`;
    alert('Player Wins')
    remove();
  } else if (document.getElementById("cs").innerText === '5') {
    document.getElementById("finalScore").innerText = `Computer Wins!`;
    alert('Computer Wins')
    remove();
  }
}

function playRound(playerChoice) {
  computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
  if (computerChoice === choices[0] && playerChoice === choices[2]) {
    document.getElementById("cs").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
    updateScore();
  } else if (computerChoice === choices[1] && playerChoice === choices[0]) {
    document.getElementById("cs").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
    updateScore();
  } else if (computerChoice === choices[2] && playerChoice === choices[1]) {
    document.getElementById("cs").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
    updateScore();
  } else if (computerChoice === playerChoice) {
    document.getElementById('scoreboard').textContent = `Draw! Computer picked ${computerChoice} and you picked ${playerChoice}!`;
    updateScore();
  } else document.getElementById('scoreboard').textContent = `You win! You picked ${playerChoice} and the computer picked ${computerChoice}.`;
  document.getElementById("ps").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
  updateScore();
}

function remove() {

  document.getElementById("ps").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("cs").innerText = 0;

  resetBtn.innerText = 'Reset';
  resetBtn.setAttribute("style",
    `display: block; margin: 0 auto 7.5rem auto; background-color: blue; color: white; padding: 2rem;  font-size: 5rem; `);
  document.getElementById('rock').removeChild(rock);
  document.getElementById('paper').removeChild(paper);
  document.getElementById('scissors').removeChild(scissors);
  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(resetBtn);
}

function removeReset() {

  document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('#buttonReset'));

  document.getElementById('rock').appendChild(rock);
  document.getElementById('paper').appendChild(paper);
  document.getElementById('scissors').appendChild(scissors);
}

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeReset();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeReset();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body id="body">

  <h1 class="title">Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
  <h2 class="title-sub">Against the computer....</h2>

  <h1 id="scoreboard"></h1>
  <h1 id="finalScore"></h1>

  <div id="scoreContainer">
    <div id="playerScore">
      <h3 class="playersTitle playerColor">Player</h3>
      <p id="ps"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="computerScore">
      <h3 class="playersTitle computerColor">Computer</h3>
      <p id="cs"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="options">
    <div id="rock">
      <button id="submitRock">ROCK</button>
    </div>
    <div id="paper">
      <button id="submitPaper">PAPER</button>
    </div>
    <div id="scissors">
      <button id="submitScissors">SCISSORS</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='resetContainer'></div>

  <p id="winner"></p>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="console.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to select it?  You have a reference to the reset button in your global `const resetBtn` variable.  Same with the rock, paper, and scissor variables as well

Comment: I am trying to select it to remove it. It is working but I still get that error message so I don't think I am going about it the right way.

Comment: Again, **Why do you need to select it? You have a reference to the reset button in your global const resetBtn variable.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting 2 listeners on the click of the `resetBtn`:

```
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeReset();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeReset();
});
```

So when you click on reset, both the listeners are triggered ; the first listener works well, but the second can't remove the element because it doesn't exist anymore.

Just remove one of the listener and it will work well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't append and remove the button. Put it in the HTML, and change its `display` style.

You also have redundant click listeners, as mentioned in the other answer. If you use this solution, you won't get an error because of it, but you should still remove the extra one.

```js
const resetBtn = document.querySelector("#buttonReset");

const rock = document.getElementById('submitRock');
const paper = document.getElementById('submitPaper');
const scissors = document.getElementById('submitScissors');

rock.addEventListener("click", function() {
  choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  playRound(choices[0]);
});

paper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  playRound(choices[1]);
});

scissors.addEventListener('click', function() {
  choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  playRound(choices[2]);
});

function updateScore() {
  if (document.getElementById("ps").innerText === '5') {
    document.getElementById("finalScore").innerText = `Player Wins!`;
    alert('Player Wins')
    remove();
  } else if (document.getElementById("cs").innerText === '5') {
    document.getElementById("finalScore").innerText = `Computer Wins!`;
    alert('Computer Wins')
    remove();
  }
}

function playRound(playerChoice) {
  computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
  if (computerChoice === choices[0] && playerChoice === choices[2]) {
    document.getElementById("cs").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
    updateScore();
  } else if (computerChoice === choices[1] && playerChoice === choices[0]) {
    document.getElementById("cs").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
    updateScore();
  } else if (computerChoice === choices[2] && playerChoice === choices[1]) {
    document.getElementById("cs").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
    updateScore();
  } else if (computerChoice === playerChoice) {
    document.getElementById('scoreboard').textContent = `Draw! Computer picked ${computerChoice} and you picked ${playerChoice}!`;
    updateScore();
  } else document.getElementById('scoreboard').textContent = `You win! You picked ${playerChoice} and the computer picked ${computerChoice}.`;
  document.getElementById("ps").innerText = Number(document.getElementById("cs").innerText) + 1;
  updateScore();
}

function remove() {

  document.getElementById("ps").innerText = 0;
  document.getElementById("cs").innerText = 0;

  document.getElementById('rock').removeChild(rock);
  document.getElementById('paper').removeChild(paper);
  document.getElementById('scissors').removeChild(scissors);
  resetBtn.style.display = "block";
}

function removeReset() {

  resetBtn.style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById('rock').appendChild(rock);
  document.getElementById('paper').appendChild(paper);
  document.getElementById('scissors').appendChild(scissors);
}

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  removeReset();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body id="body">

  <h1 class="title">Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
  <h2 class="title-sub">Against the computer....</h2>

  <h1 id="scoreboard"></h1>
  <h1 id="finalScore"></h1>

  <div id="scoreContainer">
    <div id="playerScore">
      <h3 class="playersTitle playerColor">Player</h3>
      <p id="ps"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="computerScore">
      <h3 class="playersTitle computerColor">Computer</h3>
      <p id="cs"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="options">
    <div id="rock">
      <button id="submitRock">ROCK</button>
    </div>
    <div id="paper">
      <button id="submitPaper">PAPER</button>
    </div>
    <div id="scissors">
      <button id="submitScissors">SCISSORS</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='resetContainer'></div>

  <p id="winner"></p>
  <button id="buttonReset" style="display: none; margin: 0 auto 7.5rem auto; background-color: blue; color: white; padding: 2rem;  font-size: 5rem;">Reset</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="console.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```